# LuaTeX: Change font size of mainfont without changing any other font sizes

Tags: fonts, luatex, koma-script, fontspec, fontsize

Is it somehow possible to change only the font size of the main font without changing anything else?

(The line height should also remain the same.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I'm not mistaken that would change the font size of all text that is set in `\normalsize`. (Not only the [roman] main font, but also sans and monospace.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For example, if the serif font runs very large and the monospace or sans font runs very small, what is the easiest or best solution to match the sizes?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you expand on your comment?
I'm afraid I don't understand a thing.

Comment: Some font package allow to use a scale factor, when loading the font. `fontspec`, on which you rely in the tags, i. e., supports font feature `Scale`. See section 6.2 of the manual for more information. If you need more help, please add a minimal working example to your question.

Comment: I misread, I think you can simply use `Scale` option to `\setmainfont`

Comment: Can you please add an example of your current setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really are not clear what you want to change but I suspect this does what you need

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Scale=0.5]{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}

Abc \textsf{Abc}  \texttt{Abc} \textit{Abc}
\end{document}
```

This scales the main font *family* but not other families so monospace and sans serif are not scaled but (for example) the italic version of the main font is scaled.

If you don't want to scale italic, you could reset the scale to 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Scale=0.5,
ItalicFeatures={
Scale=1
}
]{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}

Abc \textsf{Abc}  \texttt{Abc} \textit{Abc}
\end{document}
```